# The setFieldsValue method cannot be used when the antD4 form is reencapsulated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

The setFieldsValue method cannot be used when the antD4 form is reencapsulated.

Error:

```
this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue is not a function
```

[Demo by codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-n8py1)

Comment: if you console log the Ref you can see that the method that was available on the other form isn't available on your custom/local form 
`Object {current: Form}
current: Form
props: Object
context: Object
refs: Object
updater: Object
_reactInternalFiber: FiberNode
_reactInternalInstance: Object
state: null
<constructor>: "Form"​`

Comment: `.setFieldsValue()` isn't on the `ref.current` object

Comment: `Object {current: Object}
current: Object
getFieldValue: function () {}
getFieldsValue: function () {}
getFieldError: function () {}
getFieldsError: function () {}
isFieldsTouched: function () {}
isFieldTouched: function () {}
isFieldValidating: function () {}
isFieldsValidating: function () {}
resetFields: function () {}
setFields: function () {}
setFieldsValue: function () {}
validateFields: function () {}
submit: function () {}
getInternalHooks: function () {}
__INTERNAL__: Object
scrollToField: function scrollToField() {}
getFieldInstance: function getFieldInstance() {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The setFieldsValue method cannot be used when the antD4 form is reencapsulated.

when you create a Component and put an `ant Form` in it, you shouldn't expect it to behave just like an `Ant Form` (since you extends a `React Component`, not an `Ant Form`). you need `setFieldsValue`, so you can implement it like:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Form as Component } from "antd";

class Form extends PureComponent {
  formRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return <Component {...this.props} ref={this.formRef} />;
  }
  setFieldsValue(v) {
    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue(v);
  }
  getForm() {
    return this.formRef.current;
  }
}

Form.Item = Component.Item;
export default Form;
```

So you can use it with:

```
    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({
      mobile: "110"
    });
```

Or:

```
    this.formRef.current.getForm().setFieldsValue({
      mobile: "110"
    });
```

[Demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-u61q9?file=/MyForm.js)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the error because when initializing the form variable using useForm, I was not enclosing it in brackets "[]".

This code is wrong:

```
const form = Form.useForm();
```

This code is write:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
```